# Search for text within a range of cells and return Y/N

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I'm collecting reviews on fruits, people submit a google form about a fruit's name (eg. "apple") and its score. This is on sheet 1. let's say the submissions of the fruit names are on col B.
On sheet 2, i have a column (lets say col A) of all fruits (apple, pear, etc)
I would like to add a column on sheet 2 (lets say col B) that asks if there is a review for that fruit. How do I do that?
Goal: select cell from col A (list of all fruits) -> search within col B on sheet 1 to see if someone submitted a review of that fruit -> if text matches, return "Y" and if it does not exist/otherwise, return "N"
Sorry if this sounds super complicated!

I tried using vlookup but i think the "range" part stumped me. also tried if and search but not sure ;-; I don't want to have to input the fruit's name manually every time. I think i'm also having trouble as it's on two different sheets (not two completely different Google Sheets, but two sheets within one Sheet. if that makes sense)

Comment: Share a sample workbook or post sample data as text table to your question.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

To get a true/false answer, use this formula in row `2` of a free column in `Sheet2`:

`=arrayformula( if( len(A2:A), not(iserror(match(A2:A, 'Form Responses 1'!B2:B, 0))), iferror(1/0) ) )`

But it would probably be simpler to just list all fruit and count them:

`=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:C, "select B, count(B) where B is not null group by B", 1)`